# initiate class instance in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, mobx-react

I want to test my Class component using react testing library,

Facing some issues.
how can I initiate class instance variable, method?

for instance, here is my component need to be tested.

```
import {observable, action} from "mobx";
import { inject } from "mobx-react";
class MyComponent  {
  @observable homePageImagesCounts;
  get images() {
    return homePageImages.length;
  } 

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    homePageImagesCounts = props.homePageImages.length || this.images;
  }

  render(){
   if(this.homePageImages){
      return(<>Loading... </>);
   }
  return(
    <SomeComponentNeedToTest />;
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to render `MyComponent` in a test using react-testing-library?

Comment: I'm asking how to initiate ```homePageImagesCounts``` in react testing library

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with mobx, but if it is similar to any other react state provider you'll need to create a wrapper to provide whatever it is that mobx uses to connect presentational components to state. [Custom Render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) may help.